# Using JIBx to generate XSD from binding.xml

Tags: xsd, jibx

Is there a way to generate an XSD document automatically from the binding.xml used by JIBx?  This is mainly to allow offline validation of the XML documents  will be unmarshalled eventually.

I checked the JIBx homepage, it mentioned a tool called Schema Generator:

http://jibx.sourceforge.net/jibxtools/schema-example.html

but looks like the jibx-genschema.jar file is no longer part of the package anymore, as such I was wondering if there is any alternative

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to the original package.

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/codehaus/xfire/jibx/genschema/jibx-genschema.jar

Answer (score 0):

Schema generator main class is `org.jibx.binding.Compile`. It is available in `jibx-bind.jar`.
This jar can be added to your project with maven dependency org.jibx:jibx-bind:1.2.3 (for example).

Answer (score 0):

The SchemaGen tool has been included in the jibx-tools.jar file for some time. See the [JiBX Binding Generator](http://www.jibx.org/fromcode/bindgen.html) page for instructions on running tools in the jar, just substitute the target class `org.jibx.schema.generator.SchemaGen` to run the schema generator.